# how to worked with 2 different css

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3

I m new to Vue Please help.my question is that how i can merge or differentiate 2 css for example when component A load load css one and when component 2 load load css 2 
brief explanation i have landing page and dashboard page both having different style so what i want is that when landing page load css 1 get load and when dashboard page load style 2 get load i tried scoped but did not worked issue i got when i had used scoped in landing page is that it effecting dashboard i.e style 2 . if style one only available for landing page (component 1) then it will resolve my issue .is there any way to overcome this thing....

same part  of style css 1

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #4c5667;
background: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 22px;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

same part  of style css 2

```
body {
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same ids or class names across youe peoject? Afaik scoped attribute works pretty well

Comment: @funkysoul example please if you are taking about scope then i had use that the problem is that it effecting other css also

Comment: Can you show the style part of both components?

Comment: @funkysoul update my question

Comment: Now im not sure if body gets scoped aswell.. you only have 1 body regardless of the amount of components.. maybe use classes or ids?

Comment: @funkysoul is it not possible to apply css1 to component 1 so that css 1 only effect component 1 ?

Comment: well yes you can with the scoped attribute.. but not the body element...